# Which HPV types are detectable by the immune system to remove it from body?

Tags: immune-system, infection, virus, hpv

Some resources (like WHO) says that HPV can be cleared by the immune system as the following.

[WHO](https://www.who.int/en/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/human-papillomavirus-(hpv)-and-cervical-cancer)

> There are many types of HPV, and many do not cause problems. HPV infections usually clear up without any intervention within a few months after acquisition, and about 90% clear within 2 years.

Other resources I looked at about HPV as the following and they mostly have explanation of HPV.

- https://www.who.int/immunization/diseases/hpv/en/
- https://www.cdc.gov/std/tg2015/hpv.htm
- and more..

However, they don't specify which HPV types are detectable by the immune system and there is no information whether the clerance is related with the type of HPV. I also Googled for "detectable hpv types by the immune system" but unfortunately couldn't find explicit information.

My HPV Genotyping test resulted in HPV type 6. In this case I wonder which HPV types can be detectable by the immune system to remove it from the body. Is there any information about it?